# Random choice over specific values of a DF

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a big df with 17520 rows and 1000 columns. The df has only two values [0,0.05]. I would like to go to each cell of the df with the value of 0.05 and change it for a random value. The random value can only be 0 or 0.05.

I tried the following line of code:

```
 y = np.array([0,0.05])
 df.replace(0.05,np.random.choice(y))
```

However, it performs the same random choice for all of the cells with a value of 0.05, and I would like a different random choice for each cell with a value of 0.05. I tried a for loop but it takes too much time, approximately 20 minutes. I need to repeat the experiment around 100 times. 
For that reason, I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping, you coulde use  [`df.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) like this, to get a speed-up of >20x:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 0.05], size=(4000, 1000)))
 %timeit df.update(np.random.choice([0, 0.05], size=df.shape), filter_func=lambda x: x==0.05)
#498 ms ± 19.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 0.05], size=(4000, 1000)))
%timeit df.applymap(lambda x: np.random.choice([0, 0.05]) if x == 0.05 else 0)
#9.66 s ± 634 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I noticed the speed-up only increases for larger and larger dataframes, but already here applymap was taking so long that I decided not to increase the DataFrame-size further.

### How it works

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 0.05], size=(1000, 1000)))
print(df.tail(2))
df.update(np.random.choice([0, 0.05], size=df.shape), filter_func=lambda x: x==0.05)
print(df.tail(2))
#      0     1     2    3     4     5   ...   994   995   996   997   998  999
#998  0.00  0.05  0.05  0.0  0.05  0.05 ...   0.0  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.0
#999  0.05  0.00  0.05  0.0  0.05  0.05 ...   0.0  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.00  0.0
#
#[2 rows x 1000 columns]
#      0     1     2    3     4     5   ...   994   995   996  997   998  999
#998  0.00  0.05  0.00  0.0  0.05  0.05 ...   0.0  0.05  0.05  0.0  0.05  0.0
#999  0.05  0.00  0.05  0.0  0.05  0.00 ...   0.0  0.00  0.05  0.0  0.00  0.0
#
#[2 rows x 1000 columns]
```

With `update`, you can change selected values from a DataFrame. To select the values (default `np.nan`) use `filter_func= lambda x: x==0.05` and then create a DataFrame with the same size as the original DataFrame with random choices from `[0, 0.05]`. It then selects the values from the original DataFrame where the value was `0.05` and replaces it with the random vlaue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to work on your example, however, I've got the following error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: It appears then, that `df` is not a `DataFrame`. Could you post the result of `type(df)`?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, it means I have to convert it to df, don't I? or is there a more efficient function for numpy?

Comment: Yes, I would convert it to a DataFrame using `df = pd.DataFrame(df)` and this option will work for you

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works, however, I have another issue. I tried to subtract two data frames, the one from the example minus another one. And it doubles the size of the df and fill the one part with the results of the subtraction and the other with nan values.

Comment: Hi, great that it worked. If it worked for you, you might consider accepting the answer to notify future answerers and readers this solved it. If you have a different question, feel free to ask a new Question on StackOverflow. In this way, we keep the site structured: one subject per question :)