# Subtraction between two dfs yield to NAN values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `numpy.ndarray` with 17520 rows and 1000 columns. The `np.ndarray` has only two values `[0,0.05]`. I wanted to modify the cells that have a value of 0.05 for a random choice between 0 and 0.05. In order to do that I used the following functions as recommended by the post 
[Random choice over specific values of a DF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723282/random-choice-over-specific-values-of-a-df/54723613?noredirect=1#comment96281889_54723613)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(df)    
df.update(np.random.choice([0, 0.05], size=df.shape), filter_func=lambda x: x==0.05)
```

This solution worked, however, I have another `pandas.DataFrame` object, `df1`, and I need to create an additional dataframe object. The new dataframe, `df_new`, is the result of the difference of these two dataframes. I use the simple operation:

```
df_new = df1 - df
```

However, the results of `df_new` is a dataframe with different dimensions (17520 rows with 2000 columns) and `NAN` values.

Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the same columns in both the dataframes? Do you have any missing values in `df1`? What's the shape of your dataframe after `df.update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where is your problem, since you are not providing detailed information on how you build your DataFrames. In any case, you do not really have to use DataFrames for this: NumPy is certainly capable of doing what you need to do. Here is a sample code that you can use:

```
import numpy as np

# Randomly create the initial arrays, just to prove the code is OK
df1 = np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], size=(17520,1000))
df2 = np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], size=(17520,1000))

# Modify them
w1 = np.where(df1 == 0.05)
w2 = np.where(df2 == 0.05)
df1[w1] = np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], size=len(w1[0]))
df2[w2] = np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], size=len(w2[0]))

df_new = df1 - df2
```

Comment: Does this solution modify each cell with a value of 0.05 with a different random choice? because it seems your solution gives the same random choice for all of the cells with a value of 0.05. That is why I used df.update, because I want a different random choice per cell. Additionally, one df is imported from a csv file (df1) and df is created.

Comment: @JonathanBudez: Yes, it does modify each cell independently. You can easily check this, e.g., by using `df1[w1] = np.random.choice([1, 2], size=len(w1[0]))` and printing a few values of df1.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of `df` and `df1` are not the same.

Incidentally, as opposed to `update`, the following works too:

```
df[df == 0.05] = np.random.choice([0., 0.05], size=df.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, the solution stated does not work, because all of the cells with a value of 0.05 will be modified with the same random choice, and I want a different random choice per cell. That is why I used the function df.update

Comment: No, it does work. It generates an array of the same shape as the input `DataFrame`, but only the cells which are equal to `0.05` are set to the corresponding elements in that array.

Comment: I also have the following error when I use the solution
TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions

Comment: That means you're running it before the `pd.DataFrame` call (as written, it will not work for the `numpy` array.

Comment: That said, if you do not actually need `DataFrame` functionality, @MarcoLombardi's answer is preferable.

Comment: You are right, @MarcoLombardi 's answer is more suitable. Thanks